# add margin bottom to horizontal scrollbar

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, overflow

I have the following horizontal scrollbar, how to make it visible, without background, and add a padding-bottom so it's not touching the border?

[image: example]

I need it to be the same as in the photo above, with some space between the border and the actual scrollbar.

```css
.container {
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  margin: 0px 60px 0px 60px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  position: relative;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 5px;
  width: 5px;
}
.container ::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
  background: white;
}
.container ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #f0f0f0;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
.container ::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:end {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.container ::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:start {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <table>
        <thead
          <th>test</th>
          <th>test</th>
          <th>test</th>
          <th>test</th>
          <th>test</th>
          <th>test</th>
          <th>test</th>
          <th>test</th>
        </thead>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some style to table and container

```css
.container {
    padding: 3px 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
    margin: 0px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container table {
    overflow-x: auto;
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
}
```